# AWS direct connection across multiple AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-direct-connect

I don't quite understand to the full extent of AWS direct connections.

I know you can share a connection across multiple VPCs, but can the direct connection be shared across multiple AWS accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer,

Upon setting up an AWS direct connection, you are able to provision a virtual interface for another AWS account which in turn would allow the above to occur.

[image]